# How to unpack MySQL Multipoint geometry data in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, unpack, mysql-spatial

Okay, so I think I'm close here, but I'm hitting a limitation in my understanding of binary data.

I'm parsing some MySQL data inserted as geometry types, using PHP's `unpack()` as my parser, and everything was going swimmingly until I started trying to unpack complex geometry types (e.g. `MULTIPOINT`).

For a `POINT` data type, I've had good success using an unpack pattern that simply disregards the first chunk and then gives me an associative array of `type`, `order`, `lat` and `lon`:

```
$coords = unpack('x/x/x/x/corder/Ltype/dlat/dlon', $point);
// >>> [
//       'order' => 1,
//       'type' => 1,
//       'lat' => (expected value),
//       'lon' => (expected value)
//     ];
```

Naturally, applying the exact same pattern to `MULTIPOINT` geometries doesn't work the same. It gets the `order` and the `type` becomes 4, but the values of `lat` and `lon` are not at all what I'd expect. So, curious to see what the whole thing looked like, I changed the pattern to just spew it all out as "double (machine dependent size and representation)" types:

```
$coords = unpack('x/x/x/x/corder/Ltype/d*', $multipoint);
// >>> mayhem
```

What that unpacks actually includes **five** additional array items, instead of the 4 I'd expect for a multipoint with two points (2x2), and the values are totally wack. For instance, a value I'd expect to be somewhere in the 40-something-point-whatever range seems to read something like `-1.0977282851114052e-218`.

**What is the proper way to unpack a `MULTIPOINT`?** My instinct says I'm slicing the bytes where I shouldn't or casting them to an inappropriate type, but I'm not sure what those should be.

Comment: I assume you're already familiar with `SELECT ST_AsText(points) FROM mytable`?

Comment: I am, thank you. Manually parsing the points as text is my last resort, since the breadth of geometry types available is going to create a whole lot of regex-y boilerplate code using text parsing. A library feels like overkill, but that's also a second-last resort. I'm choosing to try unpacking from binary because it's clean and performant and gets me exactly what I want with one line of code. On `POINT` types at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a bit of looking, but I found [a reference](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Teradata_Data_Types/B035-1181-160K/gqz1472241187837.html) for the WKB formats of various geometries. As I guessed by looking at the output of

```
SELECT HEX(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(1 1, 2 2, 3 3)'))
```

there is a count of points after the order and type. The challenge is that the order and type are *re-declared for every point* and `unpack` doesn't have a concept of repeating a group of bytes. So you'll need to pull the bytes for each point and run `unpack` on them again. Obviously this will start to get more involved once you try accounting for more spatial types.

```
<?php
$multipoint_wkb = hex2bin("000000000104000000030000000101000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F010100000000000000000000400000000000000040010100000000000000000008400000000000000840");

function unpack_multipoint($multipoint)
{
    $data = unpack("x4/corder/Ltype/Lcount", $multipoint);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $data["count"]; $i++) {
        // the header is 1+4+8 bytes and each point record is 1+4+8+8 bytes
        $offset = ($i * 21) + 13;
        $return[] = unpack("corder/Ltype/dlat/dlon", $multipoint, $offset);
    }
    return $return;
}

print_r(unpack_multipoint($multipoint_wkb));
```

---

It's worth noting that those 4 NUL bytes are inserted by MySQL but are not part of the actual geometry object. I left them in place per your question, but if you retrieve the data using the `ST_AsWKB` function:

```
SELECT HEX(ST_AsWKB(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(1 1, 2 2, 3 3)')))
```

the extra bytes are not prepended.

Comment: Tested and confirmed, this definitely works, on both counts! Thanks for that extra tip about the extra 4 bytes, that felt really smelly. Now I think the challenge is going to be deciding whether building out those utility functions _is_ in fact going to be less work than string parsing. A lot to chew on. Question beautifully answered though, + reference to boot.

Comment: Glad to help, always nice to see a PHP question from a low-rep user that isn't just "give teh codez" ;)

Comment: Simplified a bit, assuming you're using PHP >= 7.1 which was released 2 years ago.